# Is the depth of our desire considered proof of an ultimate desirable in theology?

Tags: theology, christianity

There is a word (sehnsucht) that describes a deep and ineffable longing for something beyond description, joyous and enjoyable beyond anything in this World, that 'haunts' many people: like CS Lewis for example. I myself feel it so strongly that I feel joy and ecstasy is rendered tiny next to my hope but I fear it doesn't exist because my notion of it is so vague ( though certain things inspire it). A lot of Christians say this is the hope we were born for but there is no evidence for that scale of joy in the Bible ( it says there is no pain as well as other negation a in Heaven and mentions joy here and there). That makes me think there must be philosophical 'evidence' for so many to believe that...but I also wonder if such a desire is not, itself, proof? Are we born with a futile longing that dwarfs all other desires?

Comment: I don't have time for a full answer, but Robert Barron disucsses this sometimes, referencing Aquinas, as one argument for God's existence ("existence through desire"). Like many of these things, it is a serious argument from a well established school of thought, but there are those who disagree with it.

Answer (score 2):

Some of us are not born with such a futile longing, and there is no particular reason to suppose that such desires prove that what one desires exists or is a good idea, any more than desire to eat sweet things proves that we should eat candy all the time, or intense desires by the mentally unsound prove that they have a different God or live in a different universe than do we.

I am not exceedingly familiar with Christian philosophy and apologetics, but if such *was* taken as proof (rather than as rather weak confirming evidence), it would be an invalid argument.  When I have encountered the argument, it has always been in that context: not a proof, but a gentle suggestion that supports that world-view.

Comment: But it's not like overly desiring alchohol. Joy is holy. Can it really be so that a mortal can desire a better reality than God can create??? Surely not!

Comment: @ThomasJennings - *If* God exists, then it seems likely that God *could* create a better reality than a mortal can conceive.  But wishing I had a unicorn does not mean I have a unicorn any more than wishing that God exists and has created such a reality gets me God and that reality.  Thus: desire is not proof.

Comment: True. Sorry, it was misworded (I just assumed we would be beginning with the notion of God existing.). If he does, I've come around to thinking it logical (if He is truly infinite and perfectly good- as the Christian God is meant to be) that if such a being 'was', it's part of our definition that he is beyond us in power and goodness and, thereby, we can't outdo Him in the level of our desire for a good thing (like joy and happiness).

Comment: I think sehnsucht is fairly common. It may not be proof of God but, at least, it is an interesting 'problem'

Comment: Even _if_ God exists _and_ there is something worth yearning for it is not obviously _necessary_ that we yearn for it, or if we do that it be stronger than other yearnings.

Comment: True...but its fulfillment MUST (by definition of God) be greater than anything we can source (even in our imagintion) as mortals. Otherwise God is not God. So my yearning for something indescribebly wonderful may not be (seemingly) geared towards God but the joy that god can provide can and must trancend any of my concepts. Or God is not God because 1. He wouldn't be perfect good 2. I would have a greater depth of emotion and if God IS love, that is a severe blow.

Comment: OH- Oh this is the philosophy site! That's why I couldn't see it on the Christianity Stack Exchange (not sure why it popped up in my account over there)! Rrrright...Ah. Not event the question I thought it was. Erm. Well, yes, you're correct of course. Desire doesn't proove God. However (on a different topic) were there a God, that desire would be transended. Think that's all correct...

Comment: @ThomasJennings - I think even by Christian theology it is difficult to robustly support that God _must_ provide us with an experience that feels greater than anything we can source.  I don't think calm satisfaction is radically contrary to scripture, though Christianity.SE is the better place to ask.

Answer (score 1):

Your desire for that deep state of joy exists as a reality for many including some I know and have known. And there are definite ways to achieve it. One of them is being in the present for as long as you can which takes you in a state of acceptance and simply being. But once you practice this you realize it is easier said than done. But this is only one technique which you will find in several selfhelp books. There are many other lesser known methods  which I have learnt. Although I have not reached the state you describe, I have certainly felt it for decent durations. I can direct you to learn those.